# Create a Wordpress Docker image with plugins

Tags: wordpress, docker

Sir,

I have got my wordpress and some wordpress plugins  installed. How can I create a docker-compose.yaml so that my plugin folder contains php files inside instead of empty folders  ?

Here is my docker-compose.yaml given from others, there has no custom plugins installed :

```
version: '3'

services:
  # Database
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
      MYSQL_USER: wordpress
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress
    networks:
      - wpsite
  # phpmyadmin
  phpmyadmin:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '8080:80'
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: db
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password 
    networks:
      - wpsite
  # Wordpress
  wordpress:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: wordpress:latest
    ports:
      - '8800:80'
    restart: always
volumes: ['./:/var/www/html' , './:/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/acf-to-rest-api'  ]
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
    networks:
      - wpsite
networks:
  wpsite:
volumes:
  db_data:
```